# Attendance Tracker - Deduct points if no points within pay period

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet where I keep track of whether or not someone called in, was late or left early.  On the 1st sheet I have their names, the number of times they've called in, were late or left early, and then I have a total number of points - calling in is 2 points, being late or leaving early is 1 point.

On the 2nd sheet is where the data is recorded - the names from sheet 1 transfer to sheet 2 and then I have the days of the year from 1/1/15 to 12/31/15 in a horizontal list.  If they call in, are late or leave early, I can select one of those options as I have a drop down for each day on each line.

The problem:

I'm trying to make it so that if a person does not call in, isn't late or doesn't leave early for one pay period (2 weeks), then 2 points come off the point total on the 1st sheet.  If I have to put this into a new cell that's fine, I'm just trying to figure out how to deduct points if they've been here for that pay period with no points.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been searching all over the internet and can't find an answer to the exact problem I have.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this will be to set up a helper column that that gives the bi-weekly point totals for each employee. Once you have that in place, you could replace the current point-totaling formula on sheet 1 with something like this:

> IF(COUNTIF([range containing bi-weekly point totals],[criteria is
>   "0"]) = 0,[original point total formula],[original point total formula]
>   - (2 * COUNTIF([range containing bi-weekly point totals],[criteria is "0"])))

The IF function looks like this: IF([logical test], value if true, value if false). It runs a logical test then returns the first value if it is TRUE and the second if it is FALSE.

The COUNTIF function looks like this COUNTIF(range, criteria). It searches the range for the criteria returns the number of hits.

In the formula above, the logical test in the IF function is a check to see if there are zero instances of "0" in the employee's bi-weekly points total column. If TRUE (no zeroes in the column), it just runs the original point-totaling formula.

If FALSE, it take the number of instances of "0" in the bi-weekly points column, multiplies it by 2, then subtracts it from the result of the original point-totaling formula.

Comment: How do I setup the helper column then?  Do I start out with a date range and then drag it over ( or down ) to include the rest of the date ranges?

Comment: Actually, I probably should have said "helper table." This helper table will have a list of employees on one axis and the two-week date ranges on the other. As for the rest of it, I'd need to see the layout of the data in Sheet 2 in order to tell you exactly what formulas to use. Consider posting a screenshot or download link to the original table or a sample with a similar layout.

Comment: Here's a link to the original post that has the attendance tracker format I'm using now:

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/967173-track-attendance-points-for-a-rolling-year.html

Comment: Forgot to mention the spreadsheet is in the original post.

Comment: Any thoughts on this?